# Phpmyadmin is not working on ubuntu 22.04 with php7.4 and apache2

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-22.04

Few days back I upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and it upgraded the PHP 8.1, I had to remove php 8.1 and re install php 7.4. everything is working fine but not phpmyadmin. I installed phpmyadmin and I got **this page is not working with error 500.** I did check apache log which says following.

> [Mon Aug 15 10:48:46.498928 2022] [php7:error] [pid 18796] [client ::1:45874] script '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_databases.php' not found or unable to stat
> [Mon Aug 15 10:48:51.573540 2022] [php7:error] [pid 18796] [client ::1:45874] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 272
> [

[image]